# How to get auth_token_required in Flask_Security working?

Tags: python, flask, token, peewee, flask-security

I'm trying to build a token based backend (API) for an app using Flask in which I'm trying to use [Flask_Security](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/). Since I'm using the [Peewee ORM](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/), I've followed [this guide](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/quickstart.html#id3) to build the basic setup and I now have to build the views which should login the user and then a view which actually serves some useful data.

So my login view which returns the token looks like this:

```
@app.route('/api/login', methods=['POST'])
def api_login():
    requestJson = request.get_json(force=True)
    user = User.select().where(User.username == requestJson['username']).where(User.password == requestJson['password']).first()
    if user:
        return jsonify({'token': user.get_auth_token()})
    else:
        return jsonify({'error': 'LoginError'})
```

This works fine; I get a token as a response. I now want to protect another view using `auth_token_required` and I want to use the token as a header. So I try this as follows:

```
@app.route('/api/really-important-info')
@auth_token_required('SECURITY_TOKEN_AUTHENTICATION_HEADER')
def api_important_info():
    return jsonify({'info': 'really important'})
```

But starting Flask results in an `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__module__'`. [The documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/api.html#flask_security.decorators.auth_token_required) isn't very helpful on its usage either.

Does anybody know how I can get this to work? Any tips are welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is because the decorator does not expect any arguments (besides the function it is decorating).

```
@auth_token_required
def api_important_info():
    pass
```

The configuration values `SECURITY_TOKEN_AUTHENTICATION_KEY` or `SECURITY_TOKEN_AUTHENTICATION_HEADER` represent the location in the query params or headers, respectively, of an incoming request.

Flask-Security [automatically sends this token](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/blob/15c9ef1d075b501d8bd95687e4213be2fb9026c2/flask_security/views.py#L82-L83) to the client for future use when a JSON request is made to the login route.

---

You may be confused by the multiple authentication methods that Flask-Security provides.  Auth tokens are useful for apis where you don't have a session cookie managed by the browser.  The "normal" session based authentication is handled with [`login_required`](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/api.html#flask_security.decorators.login_required).